# How to correctly make an Observable.ajax.post request in RXJS5

Tags: ajax, reactjs, rxjs, redux-observable

Im using redux-observable with rxjs 5.5 and I am attempting to make a basic ajax POST request to a node express server.

I cant seem to find any relevant documentation or up to date working examples for Observable.ajax. Whatever solution is offered appears to throw some error, despite seeming to be the correct signature according to the actual API

My current code snippet using (redux-observable and rxjs 5.5: is as follows:

```
const loginEpic = (actions) =>  { 

    const opts = credentials => {
        const { username, password } = credentials;
        return {
            url: 'http://localhost:3001/login',
            body:{ username, password },
            headers: {  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
        };       
    };

     return actions.ofType(ActionTypes.LOGIN_REQUESTED)
        .switchMap(({credentials}) => {
            const { url, body, headers } = opts(credentials)
            return Observable.ajax.post(url, body, headers)
            .map(loginResponse => 
                loginResponse.status===200
                    ? loginResolvedAction(loginResponse.response)
                    : loginFailedAction(loginResponse.response))})
}
```

This is a nth iteration of trying to get this working, but to no avail. First issue, is the fact that I would like to set the `crossDomain` property to true, as its default to false, however, there seems to be nowhere for such a property to be set (despite the Chrome Dev Tools showing it to be there.

Here is the error:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:3001/login: Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I am using a simple express server on the back end which simply returns a basic JSON object when the url is hit on post. However, this endpoint is not hit with the current Observable.ajax.post request above.

I have a Chrome plugin which allows CORS, and using other libraries such as Axios seems to work. However, I prefer to use Observables and redux-observable and rxjs are great libraries, kudos to the authors, but I cant get to the bottom of the ajax issue. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can use redux-observable with the promises, just convert your promise to an observable using [`Observable.fromPromise`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromPromise)

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I seem to have overcome the issue, though I cannot see how this solution actually fixed it, since its not aligned with the Api. Here is my solution in case anyone has similar issues.

```
const reportsEpic = (actions) => {

    const requestSettings = token => ({
        url:`http://localhost:3001/testReports/${token}`, 
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        responseType:'json',
    })

    return actions.ofType(ActionTypes.REPORTS_REQUESTED)
        .switchMap(({token}) => 
            Observable.ajax(requestSettings(token))
            .map(reportsResponse => 
                reportsResolvedAction(reportsResponse.response)));
}
```

My confusion arises from the Api which provides for Observable.ajax.post as:

```
(method) AjaxCreationMethod.post(url: string, body?: any, headers?: Object): Observable<AjaxResponse>
```

However using ajax without the specific post metho is given as:

```
let Observable<T>.ajax: AjaxCreationMethod(urlOrRequest: string | AjaxRequest) => Observable<AjaxResponse>
```

Passing in 'POST' as a request object parameter. These two signatures seem confusing. Why would one use `ajax.post()`, if it fails where `ajax()` doesn't?

Anyone have any insight to this?

Comment: `ajax.post()` builds an `AjaxRequest` object from its arguments, where the default value for `crossDomain` is false. `ajax()` allows you to define the actual `AjaxRequest`, so you can set `crossDomain`. The `post()`, `get()` etc methods are convenience, so using `ajax()` directly is aligned with the API and is useful for your use case.